# Manually Defining Resource with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have split my resources up into interface - impl because it makes more sense but this doesn't seem to be supported by the latest release of jersey if i get it to scan for my resources.

How do I can I manually define a resource in my web.xml?
Will this work if I manually define the resource impl in the web.xml?

thanks
Alex

Comment: When you say "resource" do you mean some dependency that a Jersey service class is using or do you mean the Jersey service itself?

Comment: when i say resource I mean my RestResource, the class that defines the operations on a path, e.g. GET , POST

Answer (score 1):

[1]. Create a java class extending **javax.ws.rs.core.Application** and register your resources:

```
public class MyRESTApp 
     extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        s.add(MyResource.class);
        ....

        return s;
    }
}
```

[2]. Register the Application at web.xml
If you're using **spring**, at web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.MyRESTApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

If you're using **guice**, at web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.xx.MyGuiceServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

then create the java class MyGuiceServletContextListener extending **com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener**

```
public class MyGuiceServletContextListener 
     extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
        // Route all requests through GuiceContainer
        // IMPORTANT
        // If this property is not defined guice tries to find the @Path annotated types defied at the injector
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("javax.ws.rs.Application",
        MyRESTApp.class.getName());
        serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class,
                         params);
        });
    }
}
```